# SSRS Report table grouping on multiple columns

Tags: reporting-services, group-by, multiple-columns

I'm trying to group my SSRS report based on multiple columns and I'm sure I'm missing something here.

Here is my example

[image]

Now I want to group my table based on column 2 (Name) and then expecting a result like below

[image]

I tried to group by adding parent group and child group but the result is coming in two different columns. But I want to put it in different rows like above.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table.

Click the first cell and choose `Skill` from the dropdown. You should have a single rowgroup (probably called 'details')

Next, right-click the rowgroup and choose "Add Group - Parent Group". Choose "Name" as the Group By field and check the "Add group header" option.

This will add a new column, ignore this for now, we will delete this shortly.

Next, on the group header row, directly above where 'Skill' is, choose "Name" from the dropdown.

Finally, delete the column that was added when you added the parent group. If you are prompted choose "Delete column only" (this will retain the group).

Optionally, format the backcolor of the Name cell and that's it.

If you still cannot get it to work, let me know and I will post a full answer with images.

**UPDATED: The long version**

I started by creating a new blank report and adding a dataset `DataSet1` that recreates your dataset with the following

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(row_id int, [Name] varchar(10), Skill varchar(10))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1, 'David', 'Oracle'),
(2, 'David', 'Java'),
(3, 'David', 'HTML'),
(4, 'John', 'C#'),
(5, 'John', 'SQL'),
(6, 'John', 'HTML'),
(7, 'John', 'ASP'),
(8, 'Amy', 'Python'),
(10, 'Asa', 'Java'),
(11, 'Asa', 'Oracle')

SELECT * FROM @t
```

I then inserted a Table and dragged the Skill field onto the first cell.

[image]

Next, I right-clicked the "(Details)" row group in the row groups pane and chose "Add Group => Parent Group"
[image]

I then chose "Name" for the "Group by" column and checked the "Add group header" option.

[image]

The table now looks like this..

[image]

Next I clicked in the cell above the Skill cell (this cell is in the [Name] row group) and chose "Name" from the dropdown.

[image]

Next I right-clicked the grey column header and chose "Delete columns". I also deleted the 2 blank columns.

[image]

I added some formatting to the Name cell so the final table design looks like this.

[image]

When I run the report, the output looks like this...

[image]

If you still struggle, I suggest replicating the above using the sample dataset I created above from a new blank report and get that going first, then look at the differences in your report.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Alan, thanks for your quick reply. I've followed the same steps you mentioned but when I choose "Name" from the dropdown it is selecting as Sum(Name) but not the actual column. Did I miss something? Can you please post images so that I can compare what I missed

Comment: You are genius that works for me. Thanks for the detailed explanation. You know what I missed, when I select name from the dropdown, by default it is treating as Sum(name). So I had to type manually as [name] and it works.